# How can I convert Windows registry value InstallDate to a more standard and useful format MM/DD/YYYY in batch

Tags: unix, time, batch-file, registry

Until recently, we've been using `pstools` (specifically `psinfo.exe`) to return the operating system install date of remote machines. This feature is apparently no longer supported. The newest versions of `psinfo.exe` don't include the install date and using an older `psinfo.exe` returns garbage on our Windows 7 machines. Therefore, I'm using a remote registry query in batch to return the `InstallDate` value. This works, but the value of this date is in Unix time (number of seconds since January 1 1970). I would like this converted to `MM/DD/YYYY`. Is this feasible in batch?

more info: the registry key can be found at: `\\%RemoteComputerName%\HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion`.

Comment: More standard is YYYY-MM-DD; it corresponds to ISO 8601.

Comment: I need the MM/DD/YYYY format because the value is used by an existing python script that accepts MM/DD/YYYY. The python script gets past logins for the specified ComputerName from our login server starting at the InstallDate. I'm not familiar with retrieving this data from a login server, so I'd rather not mess with the python script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@Echo OFF

:: By Elektro H@cker

FOR /F "Tokens=2 delims==" %%# in ('WMIC OS GET InstallDate /format:list') DO (
    Call Set "Full_date=%%#"
    Call Set "Date=%%Full_date:~0,4%%/%%Full_date:~4,2%%/%%Full_date:~6,2%%"
    Call Set "Custom_Date=%%Full_date:~4,2%%/%%Full_date:~6,2%%/%%Full_date:~0,4%%"
)

Echo %Full_date%
Echo %Date%
echo %Custom_Date%

Pause&Exit
```

**Output**:

```
20120731144607.000000+120
2012/07/31
07/31/2012
Presione una tecla para continuar . . .
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. It works perfectly on a local machine. I just need to add remote registry capability. wmic returns a much cleaner string than 'reg query'. Thank you!

Comment: Update for reference: To remotely use wmic, I've used the following node property: WMIC **/node:%RemoteComputerName%** OS GET InstallDate /format:list